# Binding local variable

Tags: wpf, database, binding

I have read the answers for similar question but I still don't know how to do what I want.
I have:

```cs
public partial class DbDataToEdit : Window
{
    public SomeDBDataSet.SomeTableRow RowToModify {get;set;}
    public DbDataToEdit(SomeDBDataSet.SomeTableRow row)
    {
           RowToModify = row;
           .....
```

and
fields in XAML: TextBlock, and DatePicker which i want to bind with fields in "SomeTableRow"(someNumber , someDate). SomeTableRow is a some data[one row] from DB.

Is it possible?

optionally: How to connect elements from one row of the database table to the appropriate fields?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, you can set the source of a UI element by setting its DataContext. With this approach you can bind to almost anything. However, without seeing more details, I cannot advise much further!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the datacontext to a DataRowView instead of DataRow

```cs
public partial class DbDataToEdit : Window
{
     public DbDataToEdit ()
        {
            DataContext = RowToModify;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    public DataRowView RowToModify {get;set;}
    public DbDataToEdit(SomeDBDataSet.SomeTableRow row)
       {
           RowToModify = row.Table.DefaultView[row.Table.Rows.IndexOf(row)];
       }
}
```

and in your xaml,connect your UI elements like this

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding someNumber}"/>
```